# Are PDFs generated with Excel supported by AWS Textract?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, amazon-textract

I'm trying to build an application where I want to use AWS Textract to analyze expenses. So far it works pretty well except with PDFs that have been generated from an Excel sheet. Does it make any sense?

My code is pretty straight forward:

1. Read file:
   `file = invoice_file.read()`
2. Convert into bytearray:
   `file_bytes = bytearray(file)`
3. Analyze expense:
   `analyze_expense(Document={'Bytes': file_bytes })`

And for pdfs generated by excel files it gives me an UnsupportedDocumentException

```
botocore.errorfactory.UnsupportedDocumentException: An error occurred (UnsupportedDocumentException) when calling the AnalyzeExpense operation: Request has unsupported document format
```